# Creating a 16x16 grid using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a 16x16 grid in JavaScript. The method I'm trying to use is to create an empty `div` in HTML, and then append other divs to it, and outline their borders. I can't seem to make this work, and I've put my code below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>

</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Sets important constants and variables

const container = document.getElementById("container");
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName("gridRow");
let cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");

// Creates a default grid sized 16x16
function defaultGrid() {
    makeRows(16);
    makeColumns(16);
}

// Takes (rows, columns) input and makes a grid
function makeRows(rowNum) {

    // Creates rows
    for (r = 0; r < rowNum; r++) {
        let row = document.createElement("div");
        container.appendChild(row).className = "gridRow";
    };
};

// Creates columns
function makeColumns(cellNum) {
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cellNum; j++) {
            let newCell = document.createElement("div");
            rows[j].appendChild(newCell).className = "cell";
        };

    };
};
```

CSS:

```
.gridRow {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Your rows variable is created before the rows are appended to the dom so it will be an empty array. You need to update it after makeRows. (or you could do both in the same function to make things easier)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't using the tech that is designed to solve this problem?  [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

Comment: Well, it **is** working: https://jsfiddle.net/95kzmh1v/. You just need to set the correct CSS styles to those divs.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm doing The Odin Project, and they want people to use JS for this.  Also, wouldn't it be a lot of work manually creating all these divs?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thank you, CSS isn't my strong point lol

Comment: A homework assignment is an acceptable reason. You will discover as you continue your journey that allowing the browser to do work rather than JS is beneficial for many reasons.

Comment: Why... would you need to do this in JS? If it needs to be exactly 16 ( as opposed to some variable but square number), just set up the grid in HTML? Keep it simple, keep it easy to maintain. Don't generate what doesn't need generating.

Comment: @BaliBalo I thought so too, but just learned that an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) automatically updates when the document is changed.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It would be much cleaner to use *[CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)* and *[CSS grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_grid_layout)* to create dynamic rows and columns.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.innerText = (c + 1);
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  };
};

makeRows(16, 16);
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Try

```js
let i=0, n=16;

container.innerHTML = 
    `<div class="row">${'<div class="cell">X</div>'.repeat(n)}</div>`
    .repeat(n).replace(/X/g,_=> (i++).toString(n) )
```

```css
.row { display: flex; font-size: 9.5px; text-align: center; color: red }
.cell { width: 10px; height: 10px; margin: 1px; border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution, as provided by Gerardo Furtado is to change the CSS.

Old CSS:

```
.gridRow {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Fixed CSS:

```
.cell {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution is very primitve i guess but it worked

JS:

```
const container = document.getElementById('container');

function makeDivs(numDivs) {
for (let d = 0; d < numDivs; d++){
    let cells = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(cells)    
    }
    }

makeDivs(256);
```

css

```
#container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    width: 560px;
    height: 560px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    }

    #container > div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    }
```