# Chosen Number on Number Grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a number grid using HTML / CSS / JS. I want to add some feature that if I enter a number on input, the chosen number will be highlighted on the grid. How can I achieve this?

My sample grid code: Reference (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57550587/10427949)

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.innerText = (c + 1);
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  };
};

makeRows(5, 5);
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" style="font-size:40px;margin-bottom:50px;width:80px;" min="1" max="25" >
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const find = document.getElementById('find');

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (let i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.id = "x"+i;
    cell.innerText = (i + 1);
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  };
};

makeRows(5, 5);

const selectVal = function() {
  [...container.querySelectorAll('.grid-item')]  // all already selected 
    .forEach(cell => cell.classList.remove('selected'));   // reset the highlight
  const val = find.value;
  const cell = document.getElementById('x'+(val-1)); // your find starts at 1
  if (cell) cell.classList.add('selected'); // if found, add a class
};

find.addEventListener('input',selectVal);

container.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('.grid-item'); // make sure to handle child elements
  if (tgt) {  // we must have clicked on or in the cell
    find.value = +tgt.id.replace("x","")+1;
    selectVal();  
  }  
})
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}

.selected { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="find" style="font-size:40px;margin-bottom:50px;width:80px;" min="1" max="25" >
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Update

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const findDiv = document.getElementById('findDiv');
const gridSize = 5;

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  const max = gridSize * gridSize;
  for (let i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.id = "x" + i;
    cell.innerText = (i + 1);
    cell.classList.add("grid-item");
    container.appendChild(cell);
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    let input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "number";
    input.min = 1;
    input.max = max;
    input.classList.add("find");
    findDiv.appendChild(input);

  }
};

makeRows(gridSize, gridSize);
const inputs = findDiv.querySelectorAll("input");

const sels = new Array(gridSize);

const selectVal = function(e, inp) {
  const allSelected = [...container.querySelectorAll('.grid-item.selected')]
  if (allSelected.length === gridSize) {
    console.log(gridSize, " already selected")
    return;
  }
  const tgt = inp || e.target;
  const index = Array.from(tgt.parentNode.children).indexOf(tgt)
  const val = +tgt.value;
  sels.filter(sel => sel).forEach(sel => {
    const cell = document.getElementById(sel);
    if (cell) cell.classList.remove('selected')
  })
  if (val < tgt.min || val > tgt.max) sels[index] = "";
  else sels[index] = 'x' + (tgt.value - 1);
  sels.filter(sel => sel).forEach(sel => {
    const cell = document.getElementById(sel);
    if (cell) cell.classList.add('selected')
  })
};

findDiv.addEventListener('input', selectVal);

container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('.grid-item'); // make sure to handle child elements
  if (tgt) { // we must have clicked on or in the cell
    const cellId = tgt.id
    if (sels.find(sel => sel === cellId)) return; // we clicked on existing thing. We could TOGGLE here
    const free = sels.findIndex(sel => !sel)
    if (free !=-1) {
      inputs[free].value = +tgt.id.replace("x", "")
      sels[free] = tgt.id;
      tgt.classList.add("selected");
    }
  }
})
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}

.find {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 80px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="findDiv"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you. By the way, I have another question. How about reverse? When I clicked the numbers on the grid, it will show on the input.

Comment: Please see updated answer. It reuses the find code to highlight the cell

Comment: Last update: Cache find and reuse container; only update on click if we click IN/ON a cell

Comment: One last question, How it will  go if I added 4 more inputs and try to select 5 numbers. 1 number each input?

Comment: Hmm, now I will start charging you money ;)

Comment: It will be completely different code. I assume you want the numbers in different colours. And what happens when you change your mind, which number updates which input?

Comment: Maybe same color, I just want to maximize the 5 inputs to be shown on the grid. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So what is the use case? I click a number and the first input is filled, I click another and the second is filled, what if I change my mind and want to change the first field by clicking another number? What happens on the 6th click?

Comment: 6th click will trigger that I already input 5 numbers, If I want to change the selected numbers, update the input. Click on grid will be applicable only if the input is not yet filled.

Comment: I have added a new version. I do not have time for complete debugging but it does 95% or so of what you wanted